# How to count at runtime a number of currently existing instances of object of type X?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, reflection, instance

So I can not change object code, I have X instances of it allocated from various assemblies. I want to count how many instances there are. How to count at runtime a number of currently existing instances of object of type X using reflection or something similar not changing the object type source code?

Comment: There's not a way AFAIK without keeping a reference count yourself within the class. And it may overcount since GC may keep instances "alive" even though they're _eligible_ for GC. What's the _purpose_ of knowing the number of instances? I suspect your problem could be solved a different way.

Comment: Testing and profiling memory, so performance and extra calling GC is not as important as general possibility to get the count not modifying the object code

Comment: Then have a static counter, increment it in the constructor, decrement it in the finalizer (beware that the finalizer runs on a separate thread, so increment/decrement must be thread-safe).

Comment: If you want a clean approach, attach to the profiling interfaces, just like a profiler. The open source project shows all the magic, https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet

Comment: @KlausGütter: this will modify the code... Can you suggest on how to do it non-invasively to the code base, just in a test using Mono.Cecil?

Comment: @LexLi: I see they have a lot of timers... yet do that provide any object/constructor call counters that would not require modification of the tested codebase?